# How to print rectangle with exact size in c#?

Tags: c#, printing, shapes

I am new to Dot Net, I want to print a rectangle with 20mm width and 8mm height exactly if I measure with scale. I also want to print text exactly in the middle of rectangle.Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

---

I am really sorry for not being clear earlier. I have tried using "PageUnits" its working fine. However, I have problem with the margins.

I am able to print correct margins(8.8mm left and 22mm Top) if I am using the printer "HP LaserJet P2035n". If print using "Canon iR2020 PCL5e" I am getting incorrect margins(8.1mm left and 8.0mm Top) where I should get 8.8mm left and 22mm top margins. Can someone explain me where I am doing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class DrawShape
    {
        public static void DrawRec()
        {
            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrintPage += doc_PrintPage;
            doc.Print();
        }

        static void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            PageSettings PageSet = new PageSettings();
            float MarginX = PageSet.PrintableArea.X;
            float MarginY = PageSet.PrintableArea.Y;
            float x = (float)(8.8-((MarginX/100)*25.4));
            float y = (float)(22-((MarginY/100)*25.4));
            g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, 20, 8);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start with this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            formGraphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
            formGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, 20, 80);
        }
    }
```

You can then using DrawString on the Graphics object to draw text inside your rectangle.